# Delete generated files when original is modified with Apache Ant

Tags: ant

I want to delete the generated files (".tmp" and ".bak") in the build directory when the source file (".xml)" is modified with Apache Ant. All files have the same name, but different extentions.

I'm not able to create the fileset to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [file mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) in place of a fileset.